# How to create a custom template for blog in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drupal

I am completely new to Drupal. I want to create a custom template for content type of blogs. Would anyone please guide me through the steps to create it?

Comment: What did you find when you researched this problem yourself?

Comment: Try google and search "creating drupal 7 custom template"

Comment: I did some research. I am able to create a page with a custom template for a content type but i want to create a template for a page that lists all blogs.  
I actually want to create a page that lists the following blocks : 1. recent blog with its title,body, author name and date. 2. a block which lists 5 most recent blogs by title 3. a block which has list of monthly archives like : Archive november 2014 december2014 january 2015 february 2015 I dont know how to achieve this :(

Answer (score 0):

By "custom template for content type of blogs" I assume you mean how the Blog content displays? If so, I recommend you use Views, but if you are comfortable with PHP you could create a custom template file. Check out [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42648/create-custom-template-for-blog), it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify which version of drupal are you working on. This is important because there are variations in naming the template file.

Here are the steps:

1. In your drupal directory go to **/sites/all/themes/[name-of-your-theme]/templates**
2. Look for the file **node.tpl.php**
3. Duplicate **node.tpl.php** and name it as follows:

   - **node-[content-type].tpl.php** (single "-" for Drupal 6)
   - **node--[content-type].tpl.php** (double "-" for Drupal 7)

**OR** you can just create this file directly and refer on node.tpl.php for the variables.

Note: Drupal has the ability to cache, depending on your configuration you may need to clear the cache to see it take effect.

Comment: I actually want to create a page that lists the following blocks : 1. recent blog with its title,body, author name and date. 2. a block which lists 5 most recent blogs by title 3. a block which has list of monthly archives like :
Archive

    november 2014
    december2014
    january 2015
    february 2015

I dont know how to achieve this :(

Comment: Your question should be something like this "How can I create a listing of blogs in Drupal"

One way to do this listing is by view. Create a view with a view type of nodes. Fill up the views default setting, then add a display with a display type of block. You can customize the output by going to Theme Information (you can find this in advance options in D7) 

Play with the filtering and fields to get the output that you desire

Comment: thank you! I did this. also I want to print a particular blog`s content in another content type`s page. say in a "basic page" content type`s page. how do i do this?

Comment: there's a lot of way to do this, you can google how to print a block in template. when you know how to do this apply this in a basic page where input is set to php? but thats not clean. you can program the block to appear in a specific page and a specific location by configuring it. views block automatically appear there.  You can also customize contents by using the panels module.